# Moving values from one cell to another only if two separate cells match

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am attempting to find a formula that will pull values from a cell only if two separate cells match. I did this already with =sumif by using the formula **=SUMIFS(E7:E24, A7:A24,"Won", D7:D24, D31)** this would add the numbers I needed in E7:E24, check to make sure A7:A24 contained the word "Won", and then cross reference D7:D24 with D31 to make sure the two matched to give me my goal. I needed this due to being able to use a drop down menu instead of manually inputting lots repetitive info. I am trying to do this again but I am unable to use the =sumifs formula as I am trying to bring in words and not numbers. Google hasn't been much help in this endeavor either. I have created a sample sheet [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HQYp55PyKdLQ90EM9txukpqU3i9ZpB-UeykzunSGadM/edit?usp=sharing) with some basic info provided. J2 contains my issue and shows which cells I am trying to pull from. Any assistance on this would be wonderful!

Comment: what is the expected output for J2?

Comment: J2 needs to contain G10:AT10, the exact entry is based on G6:AT6,A2:F2 matching exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IF(REGEXMATCH('C'!G6:AT6, A2), 'C'!G10:AT10, )))
```

[image: 0]

for full array you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP($A$2, $AD$6:$AT, ROW($A$5:$A$8)+MATCH(K1, $A$10:$A, 0)-1, 0))
```

[image]